# Laravel Fortify verification.notice route not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-fortify

I am trying to use Laravel Fortify for authentication. All routes work fine except for email verification.

I have done everything according to docs as far as I understand:

1. Impemented Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail interface in the User model
2. emailVerification feature is enabled in fortify configuration file's features array

   ```
    'features' => [
    Features::registration(),
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    Features::emailVerification(),
    // Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    // Features::updatePasswords(),
    // Features::twoFactorAuthentication(),
   ```

   ],
3. Added to boot method of FortifyServiceProvider

   ```
        Fortify::verifyEmailView(function () {
        return view('auth.verify');
    });
   ```

Yet I keep getting the following error:

```
Route [verification.verify] not defined.
```

And *verification.verify* route is not in artisan route:list although it should be added to the list like *login* and *register* routs by Laravel Fortify.

Why is the route missing/not loaded?

I tried *artisan route:clear* and *cache:clear* without luck.

Laravel v10.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I was editing wrong Fortify configuration file:

```
vendor/laravel/fortify/config/fortify.php
```

While I should edit that file:

```
config/fortify.php
```

Now everything works as expected.